# Multiple random sprites per GameObject in Unity 5

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite, gameobject

I'm attempting to write a "card matching" game in Unity 5, and I want to generate some cards which are 2-in-1. That is, they have two faces the player must match against rather than 1. In fact, I would like to generate 3, 4, and 5 faced cards as well.

I have two questions.

1. I don't know if it would be more efficient to generate the groupings randomly and assemble the cards programmatically or have a great many more sprites and prefabs simply predefined.
2. Assuming it is more efficient to generate programmatically, I'm not sure how to go about it. I think I want to programmatically add multiple sprites to a single object and position and rotate them programmatically. I'm having trouble figuring out how to do that.

Comment: You need a behaviour `Card` to represent cards. It should have a private `CardId` property marked with `[SerializeField]`, a private `CardSpritePath` property marked with `[SerializeField]`, and public method `CanBeMatchedWith(Card other)`, which checks for `CardId` internally. During `Start()`, it loads a sprite from `CardSpritePath` and assigns it to `SpriteRenderer`. If by "efficient", you mean "performance", do not care about it until everything works. If many sprites are a bottleneck, you can batch them later

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question should be deleted here and asked on **gamedev.com**.  It is not relevant to this site.